# Dynamic property setter with linq expressions?

Tags: vb.net, lambda, properties, linq-expressions

I want to create a simple function that does the following:

```
Sub SetValue(Of TInstance As Class, TProperty)(
  ByVal instance As TInstance,
  ByVal [property] As Expression(Of Func(Of TInstance, TProperty)),
  ByVal value As TProperty)

  '...
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
Dim x As New Person
SetValue(x, Function(p) p.FirstName, "John Doe")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple:

```
Sub SetValue(Of TInstance As Class, TProperty)(
   ByVal instance As TInstance,
   ByVal [property] As Expression(Of Func(Of TInstance, TProperty)),
   ByVal value As TProperty)


  'TODO: validate nulls
  If [property].Body.NodeType <> ExpressionType.MemberAccess Then _
    Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid lambda expression.", "property")


  Dim body = DirectCast([property].Body, MemberExpression)
  Dim member = DirectCast(body.Member, PropertyInfo)
  member.SetValue(instance, value, Nothing)
End Sub
```

HTH